# Typo3 backend crashed after virtual machine stopped unexpectedly

Tags: ubuntu, typo3, virtual-machine, typoscript

I have installed typo3 9.5 using composer on an Ubuntu virtual machine (Virtual Box VM). Everything was working correctly until the VM stopped unexpectedly. Now I can see the Typo3 frontend page, but the backend shows me an error instead of the login page. The error says:

> Oops, an error occurred! Class
>   'Standard_action_SystemInformationDropDown_20940fed1a82f6d95c4f08802f1d7df50892e847'
>   not found

[image: Error Screenshot]

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error points to an invalid cache entry. Probably a cached Fluid template.

Probably clearing the caches by visting the InstallTool (`/typo3/install.php`) » Maintenance » Flush TYPO3 and PHP caches would be enough.

If not (or if the InstallTool is not accessible due to the error), I suggest to delete the TYPO3 directories `./typo3temp` and `./var` and then let TYPO3 recreate them via the InstallTool » Maintentance » Directory Status.

In a composer install, running `composer install` or at least `composer dump` might be good measure after bringing a system back from an invalid state.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to log in to InstallTool via `//your_domain/typo3/install.php` and clear the cache with proper button

If this will not help then you can clear temp files manually from `typo3temp` folder and `var/cache`